# Creating a new instance of a class in typescript

Tags: class, typescript, dependency-injection

I'm trying to create a new instance of a class, with empty values but I'm struggling with the code.

Here's my class file code:

```
export class MyTimeDefinition {
    RequestCodes: Array<RequestCodes>;
    BalanceCodes: Array<BalanceCodes>;
    ID: number;
    Description: {
        SelectedLanguage: number,
        Values: {
            LanguageID: number,
            ValueID: number,
            Value: string
        }[]
    };
    IsDataLoaded: boolean;
    TypeName: string;
}

export interface RequestCodes {
    ID: number;
    StringValue: string;
}

export interface BalanceCodes {
    ID: number;
    StringValue: string;
}
```

and in my component I try to create a new instance of the class like this:

```
//Create New MyTime-Definition
public createNewMyTimeDefinition() {
    let newMyTimeDefinition = new models.MyTimeDefinition();
    console.log(newMyTimeDefinition);
}
```

the result of my console.log is `MyTimeDefinition {}` how can I create the variable *newMyTimeDefinition* that has all the attributes of the class and not just an empty object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a `constructor` in `MyTimeDefinition` class where you add some values to the variables inside your class.
Something like this:

```
export class MyTimeDefinition { 
    ...
    //Some other variable
    constructor(){
        this.mystringvariable = "my string value";
    }
}
```

And, as you will see, when you create a new class intense by calling the constructor the variables of your class will be not empty.

Comment: I added the constructor in my class like you said, but right now I receive "Cannot set property 'SelectedLanguage' of undefined" for some reason, however according to VS it should be defined.

Comment: Because you need to instantiate first the Description object and then try to access to the the SelectedLanguage